# Issue with Strlen() functionality in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, sizeof

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
char arr[]= {'g', 'e', 'e', 'k', 's'}; 
printf("%d %d", sizeof(arr),strlen(arr));
return 0;
}
```

i am getting output as 5 6 , i am not able to understand why I am getting 6 instead of 5 because the character array length is 5?

Comment: 1. That's not a string. 2. You're not using `strlen` (which is good, because ...1).

Comment: *"i am getting output as 5 6"* No you aren't. You're getting output as 5. That said, `%d` is the wrong format specifier for a `sizeof` result, so I suppose it could be UD. (Also note that `sizeof` is not a function, no `()` needed.)

Comment: You should use `%zu` as it iz the correct format specifier for `size_t`.

Comment: @CoolGuy: Or use `%d` and cast to `int`: `printf("%d\n", (int)sizeof arr);` But yes, `%zu` is better (unless you're stuck with an ancient implementation that doesn't support it).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: what does it mean `UD`? do you mean `UB`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder your second comment is not entirely true, there are possible operands to `sizeof` that have to be paranthesized (not in this case here)... so it's common practice to always write it as if it was a function.

Comment: @AlterMann: Doh! Yes, I did.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: That's true for **all** operators. The operands to `+` need `()` sometimes, too, that doesn't mean that you write `a = (b) + (c)` all the time. The `()` are harmless, of course, so if people want to use them with `sizeof`, there's nothing *wrong* with it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it's just common usage. And I guess the reason is `sizeof` can easily be seen having "function semantics". Of course it's important to know it's actually an operator, but a lot of existing code seems to agree writing it like it was a function is a readable way.

Answer (score 0):

To get the size of `string`, `strlen()` should be used.

`strlen()` needs a `\0` terminated string

Comment: so in this case there is no '\0' then what will happen , will the compiler keep on searching for the '\0' , so can u clearly explain how strlen() will behave in this situation.

Comment: @user3290550: The *compiler* won't do anything. The code it generates will start searching your `char[]` array and continue until either A) You get a segfault for accessing memory you shouldn't access, or B) It finds a `\0`. The behavior of `strlen` with a memory block that isn't explicitly null-terminated is undefined. But, you know, it won't be useful. :-)

Comment: so why it's only 6 ,it can be 7 also, can u please see the code again

Comment: @user3290550 **The behavior of strlen with a memory block that isn't explicitly null-terminated is undefined.** That means it can be anything, `6` or `7` or `halo`.

Comment: [sigh] 'o can u clearly explain how strlen() will behave in this situation' - homework tell.

Comment: @MartinJames may be, or may be he really wants to map it into the brain of his. I use to have this problem, something explained in text book terms is harder to understand, unless until explained with a particular example that is floating in my head.

Answer (score 0):

A `char` array ended with `'\0'` is treated, also, as a string; hence note the array size of `arr` is `5` whereas the array size of `str` is `6`, however the string size of `str` (`strlen`) is `5`,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  char arr[]= {'g', 'e', 'e', 'k', 's'};
  char str[]= {'g', 'e', 'e', 'k', 's', '\0'};

  printf("sizeof arr %d \n", sizeof(arr));
  printf("sizeof str %d \n", sizeof(str));
  printf("strlen str %d \n", strlen(str));

  return 0;
}
```

namely,

```
sizeof arr 5 
sizeof str 6 
strlen str 5
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write `char arr[] = {'g', 'e', 'e', 'k', 's'};` then you have array of characters and so `sizeof(arr)` give you the length of the arr in bytes which is 5. But When you write `char arr[] = "geeks";` you will have a '\0' character automatically at the end of the arr and so the size of arr is 6 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

According to the C Standard (7.1.1 Definitions of terms)

> 1 A string is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and
>   including the first null character.

and

> ...The length of a string is the number of bytes preceding the null
>   character

Function `strlen` (7.23.6.3 The strlen function) counts the number of characters in a character array that precede the null character:

> 2 The strlen function computes the length of the string pointed to by
>   s.

As for the `sizeof` operator then (6.5.3.4 The sizeof and alignof operators)

> 2 The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which
>   may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The size is
>   determined from the type of the operand.

This declaration declaraes a character array size of which is determined by the number of initializers

```
char arr[]= {'g', 'e', 'e', 'k', 's'};
```

According to the C Standard (6.7.9 Initialization)

> 22 If an array of unknown size is initialized, its size is determined
>   by the largest indexed element with an explicit initializer.

So the array has exactly 5 elements. Its type is `char[5]` abd according to the definition of the `sizeof` operator expression

```
sizeof(arr),
```

yields the size in bytes of its operand `arr` that is 5.

The array does not contain the null character. So function `strlen` is unable to count the number of bytes that precede the null character. In this case its behaviour is undefined. It will count all bytes beyond the array until it enciunters a null character. Thus expression

```
strlen(arr)
```

can yield any result greater than 5.

You could initialize the array with a string literal as for example

```
char arr[]= {"geeks"};
```

In this case the array also is initialized by the null character of the string literal. This initialization is equivalent to

```
char arr[]= {'g', 'e', 'e', 'k', 's', '\0'};
```

In this case the size of the array

```
sizeof(arr),
```

is equal to 6. And as the array has the null character expression

```
strlen(arr)
```

will count exactly 5 characters that precede the null character.